# Formalization in PA in the Kritchman-Raz proof

Tags: lo.logic, peano-arithmetic, kolmogorov-complexity

In their [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4974) Kritchman and Raz present a proof of Gödel's second theorem using Kolmogorov complexity. To make it work, they operate in some (weak) formal theory $T$ that incorporates some arithmetic, say Peano arithmetic ($\mathbf{PA}$).

Let $m$ be the number of integers $0 \leq x ≤ 2^{L+1}$, such that, $K(x) > L$. They argue:

[image: Kritchman-Raz argument]

Equation 2 is just $\Sigma_1$-completeness of $T$ over formulas and $r = 2^{L+1} + 1 − i$.

My issue is with step 4. Kritchman-Raz seem to interchange freely two different types of existential quantifiers concerning $y_1,\dots,y_r$, one formal within the theory $T$ (as in step 1,2), and one in the metatheory in step 3. But $\exists \text{ different } y_1,\dots,y_r \, \varphi(y_1,\dots,y_r)$ within a formal theory doesn't guarantee existence of concrete instances (meta theoretic numbers) $y_1,\dots,y_r$ such that $\varphi(\bar{y_1},\dots,\bar{y_r})$ within that same formal theory, in general. And it seems to me this is exactly what Kritchman-Raz are doing here. However, I'm very much a beginner w.r.t. formalizations in arithmetic. Is my analysis correct? If so, how do we fix it?

I asked a similar question first on MSE, but got no response (even after having set a bounty). I hope this question is on the appropriate level for MO. If not, my apologies.

Comment: Here, $2^L$ is a standard constant. Already Robinson's arithmetic proves that the only numbers below $\overline{2^L}$ are the standard integers $\overline0,\overline1,\dots,\overline{2^L}$.

Comment: @Emil You mean that $Q$ proves $\exists x \leq \overline{2^L} (\varphi(x)) \to \varphi(\bar{0}) \lor \dots \lor \varphi(\overline{2^L})$? And then we use a formalized proof by cases, in the sense that $T \vdash \varphi(\bar{0}) \lor \dots \lor \varphi(\overline{2^L})$ and $T \vdash \varphi(\bar{n}) \to \psi$ for all $n \leq 2^L$ implies $T \vdash \psi$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. --

Comment: @Emil Is Pudlak and Hajek a good start? Or do you have better suggestions?

Comment: I’m not sure. Hájek&Pudlák is quite comprehensive and pays attention to formal details, but it may be too terse for a beginner. You might try a classic textbook like Shoenfield, or take an inspiration in https://mathoverflow.net/q/44620 .

Comment: @Emil Thanks for your suggestions. Terse shouldn't be too big of a problem, I've have done several graduate courses in mathematical logic. However, with these type of arguments it is my experience that sometimes I need to be pointed in the right direction, otherwise I spend way too much time on something that's actually fairly simply. Like this question for instance. My problem is is that I don't have a good source to ask such (potentially) low level question.